# How to position buttons in tkinter like in photo?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid

I have a project with Python but I can't arrange the buttons. How can I arrange them like that in the photo?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPCMI.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any code that you can share?

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the problem down into smaller parts. Looking at the photo I see three distinct areas: a blue bar across the top with a title, a row of labels, entry widgets, and buttons, and then a grid of buttons. So, start by learning how to stack three horizontal regions on top of each other.

Next, you can focus on each section separately:

- For the top, learn how to fill the region with a single blue label.
- For the row of buttons, learn how to add labels, entry widgets, and buttons from left to right
- For the grid of buttons, learn how to place widgets in a grid.

You can do all of this with two geometry managers: `grid` and `pack`. `pack` is best at edge-to-edge alignment (eg: left-to-right, top-to-bottom). `grid` is good for creating a grid. They are both fairly well documented on multiple sites on the internet.

If I were doing this, I would use `pack` to stack three frames top-to-bottom, with the bottom frame configured to fill all of the remaining space. I would also use `pack` to lay out the labels, entry widgets, and buttons in the second section. I would use grid to lay out the buttons in the third section. That isn't the only way, but it's the one I think requires the least amount of code.

For example, the first step is to create the three frames and lay them out. It might look something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

title_frame = tk.Frame(root)
tool_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame = tk.Frame(root)

title_frame.pack(side="top", fill=x", expand=False)
tool_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
button_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

After that, it's just a matter of doing the same sort of process for each section.

Tip: During initial development, it is helpful to temporarily give each frame a distinct color, a thick border, and/or an estimated width and height so that you can visualize them. You can go back and adjust the colors and borders after you have everything working, and the widget width and height should automatically adjust after you start to add the other widgets.